# UICollectionView Scrolling issue

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uicollectionview

I am developing an iPhone app that consists of `UICollectionViews` on `UITableView`

To make each Collection scrolls horizontally . All steps are work perfectly except when I start to scroll each `UICollectionView` the `UICollectionViewCell` method is reuse and

I am getting a problem with the label , the problem in the image below [image]

I faced this issue with the title of each collection on scrolling the table view and I did this

```
NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"CellId%d%d",indexPath.row,indexPath.section];
TableViewCell *cell = (TableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if(!cell) 
{ 
    cell = [[TableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
```

I assigned unique identifier to each cell , there is any suggestions that can help ? :)

Comment: Cross check the code of reusing the collectionView and TableView cells. Might be you are not reusing cells properly.

Comment: I do not know your codes exact problem but this part seems to be wrong. NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"CellId%d%d",indexPath.row,indexPath.section];

Comment: I changed this code and i did this in uitableviewcell
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";
and the same issue remains

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this code in `cellForRoAtIndexPath` methods

```
for (UIView *v in [cell subviews])
        [v removeFromSuperview];
```

Tell me if its working or not :)

Comment: yes this works good but can you explain the concept of this solution :)

Comment: this code remove the subview of cell and init new subview when delegate method called.