# collection view scrolling issue

Tags: ios, iphone

collection view scrolling issue :

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView 
 cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
        photoFuncVal=1;
size=CGSizeMake(85, 85);
UICollectionViewCell *cell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];
UIImageView *icon=(UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{
    NSData *imgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString   stringWithFormat:@"%@",[_responseAdvPicArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] ]]];
    if (imgData)
    {
        //image = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];
        image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imgData];
        //icon.image = image;
        scaledImage=[UIImage imageWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 4.0)];
        scaledImage=[self imageWithImage:image convertToSize:size];
        if (image)
        {
           dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
           //icon.image=scaledImage;
           cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:scaledImage];

            });
         }
       }
    });

    cell.layer.borderWidth=4;
    cell.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor whiteColor]CGColor];
    return cell;

    }
```

the problem is that when the collection view is scrolled the images are reloaded and also duplicate at times

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22325552/uicollectionview-scrolling-issue

Comment: i checked the above link but no help. i am not having any subview on the collection view cell. it has only images. So what changes should i make in my code?

Comment: How do you adding images on cell?

Comment: i am not having any label or any subview on the collection view cell. it contains only images.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView 
 cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
        photoFuncVal=1;
size=CGSizeMake(85, 85);
UICollectionViewCell *cell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];
**cell.backgroundColor = nil;**
UIImageView *icon=(UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{
    NSData *imgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString   stringWithFormat:@"%@",[_responseAdvPicArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] ]]];
    if (imgData)
    {
        //image = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];
        image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imgData];
        //icon.image = image;
        scaledImage=[UIImage imageWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 4.0)];
        scaledImage=[self imageWithImage:image convertToSize:size];
        if (image)
        {
           dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
           //icon.image=scaledImage;
           cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:scaledImage];

            });
         }
       }
    });

    cell.layer.borderWidth=4;
    cell.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor whiteColor]CGColor];
    return cell;

    }
```

Comment: i am not having any label or any subview on the collection view cell. it contains only images

Comment: Can you try first set cell.backgroundColor=nil; and then the actual image pattern?

Comment: Can you try to add cell.backgroundColor=nil; after dequeue only ?i am editing your code to explain what i am saying.

Answer (score 0):

Register your cell like this :

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CollectionCell";

[self.collectionHome registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"CollectionViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CollectionCell"];

CollectionViewCell *cell ;
if(cell==nil)
{
    cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
}
```